# ‘GL_VERTIEX_SHADER’ was not declared in this scope - when it is <--It was a typo.

Tags: c++

This is really weird,

line 1752 of glew.h:

```
#define GL_VERTEX_SHADER 0x8B31
```

Under the GL_VERSION_2_0 header guard

I have this code:

```
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if(GLEW_OK != err)  {
         ::std::cout<<"Error: "<<glewGetErrorString(err)<<"\n";
    }
    //GLuint shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTIEX_SHADER); <--FAILS
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(0x8b31); <--WORKS
    ::std::cout<<"Shader: "<<shader<<"\n"<<"Errorstr: "<<
        glewGetErrorString(glGetError())<<"\n";
#ifdef GL_VERSION_2_0
        ::std::cout<<"OKAY I have 2.0\n";
#endif
    ::std::cout<<glGetString(GL_VERSION)<<"\n";
```

Output:

```
Shader: 1
Errorstr: No error
OKAY I have 2.0
4.4.0 NVIDIA 331.38
```

If I use GL_VERTEX_SHADER however I get a symbol not found, weirdly my IDE can't find it either.

Answer (score 1):

I've just noticed, I actually spelled "VERTEX" wrong. It works now. I feel really silly.

It took a title to make me see that though

Comment: Happens to the best of us

Comment: Hour and a half @JustSid, I even REBUILT Glew.